# relationship between AWS CloudFormation Stack name and and resources names

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I have created a CloudFormation stack which has name `Demo-test-excise`. At the same time, I also created AuroraMySQL,IAM Role, IAM Policy, Cloudwatch. After I uploaded the template file to AWS console, then I found the names of AuroraMySQL,IAM Role, IAM Policy, Cloudwatch all starts with `Demo-test-excise`. Why the names of resources will cover the stack name?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why it is helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Most resources allow you to explicitly specify the name, such as [RoleName](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html#cfn-iam-role-rolename). If you don't do this, CFN will auto-generate one which also is also helpful in many scenarious.

The fact that the stack name is in the auto-generated names is very helpful. It allows you quickly identify **which resources where generated by which stack** when you use AWS console or CLI to list such resources. This is much more user-friendly then just using totally random names.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.